# Which JAR file contains the JsonProcessingException class?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jar, jackson

When I try to use Jackson 2.1.1 with the following jar files (in Spring 3.2.2),

- jackson-core-2.1.1.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.1.1.jar
- jackson-databind-2.1.1.jar

I get the following exception.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException

So I think, the class `JsonProcessingException` is contained by the `jackson-core-asl-2.1.1.jar` file (I'm not quite sure though) but I cannot see this file in the [download](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload). So where to get this file to resolve that exception?

---

[`jackson-all-1.9.8.jar`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.8/jackson-all-1.9.8.jar) contains necessary classes including the class `org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException` and JSON also works fine but I'm not sure this is perfectly compatible as I'm using  classes from Jackson 2.1.1 for object mapping. Therefore I'm looking for the `jackson-core-asl-2.1.1.jar` file but I can't see such a JAR file. I can only see `1.x.x` versions [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjacksoncoreasljar.htm).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In version 2.1.2, that class is called `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException`, and it's in the jackson-core jar. Jackson [changed its packaging for version 2.0](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonRelease20#Changing_Java_packages), along with numerous other things.

It seems you have some code that was written against an older version of Jackson, and is trying to load the class under an old name. You will need to either update this code, or use an old version of Jackson.

Comment: I have downloaded these JAR files of the version 2.1.2 - `jackson-core-2.1.2.jar`, `jackson-databind-2.1.2.jar` and `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.1.2.jar` and I got this exception - `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`. No solution ever found  with the help of Google.

Comment: With Jackson **2.1.1**, I had to register `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` for it to work. Earlier, it was trying to use `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` by default. Hence, the exception. It now works fine with Jackson **2.1.1**.

Answer (score 1):

Use jackson-all-1.9.9 jar instead of the later versions(2.x.x.) of jackson-core, jackson-annotations and jackson-databind. Here is the [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjacksonall199jar.htm).